# How to set order of Middlewares in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

So I am using this open-source available MDW: https://github.com/snok/asgi-correlation-id which essentially just generates and adds a unique Correlation ID for incoming requests in FastAPI app.

However, I have created another custom middleware for my app, this way:

```py
@app.middleware("http")
async def some_custom_mdw_function(request: Request, call_next):
    # some operation  I do here
    # which also requires me fetching the 
    # correlation_id created via the asgi-correlation-id
    # I have code line over here like:

    asgi_corr_id = correlation_id.get() # a function imported from asgi-correlation-id library
```

This however gives me an error sometimes, since apparently, those times, this some_custom_mdw_function MDW is called before the asgi-correlation-id MDW, and hence the correlation ID is not found.

How do I ensure that asgi-correlation-id MDW is called always before some_custom_mdw_function MDW? Is there a way to set the order of executions for MDW in FastAPI?

Comment: Have you tried using `app.add_middleware` instead of a decorator? Starlette specifies that the order should be stable, so there might be something else going on here.. https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/479

Comment: Didn't know that there is an order, and that, FastAPI calls all middlewares in the reverse order in which they were added! I tried it out and it works like a charm. Thanks.